# Adding a custom login form when using Default Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using the Default Membership Provider that ASP 4.5 WebForms uses (using my own database) and I am facing a problem regarding the login form. I want to make a custom one  because I am using a fancy CSS/HTML5 code for it, but using the default control given my Visual Studio just breaks it, and I want to execute some custom code on the login press while also maintaining the controls that Default Membership Provider already brings (like Password Failure count, etc). What method/process should I call or what custom code should I write so that when the user writes the username and password it uses the values of those textboxes for login purposes? I tried dabbling into the Login button of the Login controller but its too limited in scope and the tables still break a bit the design. Any help is greatly appreciated!

As Promised this is the full code I used with some truncations regarding query and stuff:

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;
        string passwordQuestion = "";
        string passwordAnswer = "";

        if (Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer)
        {
            passwordQuestion = txtQ.Text;
            passwordAnswer = txtA.Text;
        }

       try
       {
            MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text,
                                                           txtEmail.Text, passwordQuestion,
                                                           passwordAnswer, true, out status);




            if (newUser == null)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
               Label1.Text = GetErrorMessage(status);
            }
            else
            {


                string connect4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InternalConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection(connect4))
                {

                    string query4 = "INSERT INTO [UserInfo] ([UserName], [ConfirmationToken], [Validated], [FullInfo], [EMail], [SocioNum], [Birthday], [PostalAddress], [Zip], [City], [State], [Phone], [Fullname], [SocialSecurityEncrypted], [JoinDate]) VALUES (@UserName, @ConfirmationToken, @Validated, @FullInfo, @EMail, @SocioNum, @Birthday, @PostalAddress, @Zip, @City, @State, @Phone, @Fullname, @SocialSecurityEncrypted, @JoinDate)";
                    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, conn4);
));
                    string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
                    Random r = new Random();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
                    {
                        int idx = r.Next(0, 35);
                        sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1));
                    }
                    string token = Convert.ToString(sb);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmationToken", (token));
(parameters here)



                    cmd4.CommandTimeout = 240;
                    conn4.Open();
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn4.Close();

                    Session["Fullname"] = txtNombre.Text;
                    Session["token"] = token;



                }

                //CUSTOM EMAIL CODE

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("servername");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("fromhere@tothere.com");
                mail.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Subject = "Subject";
                mail.Body = "HTML CODE HERE while sending token for verification.";


                SmtpServer.Port = 25;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);







                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch
       {
           Label1.Visible = true;
           Label1.Text = "Erro. Verify info..";
        }
    }



    public string GetErrorMessage(MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                return ".";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                return ".";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                return "Password invalid.";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                return "";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                return "";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                return "";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                return "Invalid";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                return "Error";

            case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

            default:
                return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
        }
    }


}
```

}

What this does it registers the ASP.NET Default Membership provider but I created a second table for further information and as well a ConfirmationToken that generates and is sent by email to the user, who then clicks the confirmation like and a confirmation page reads the URL parameters and if it validates it turns on a boolean in the UserInfo table. In the login process before the actual ASP memebrship login I have a user verification query that verifies if the user is already validated, and if so it continues with the default asp membership login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Membership class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx), [MembershipUser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.aspx), and [Forms Authentication class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) and create your own login form.  The login control itself doesn't really have much logic in it.

For example, to set the authentication cookie, use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.  To validate the password, use `MembershipProvider.ValidateUser`.  To see if a user is locked out from too many invalid password attempts, use `MembershipUser.IsLockedOut`.

Comment: Checking into it. That's exactly what I was looking for. Googling Default Membership provider microsoft or msdn didn't net me that result; frustrating :p

Comment: When you get it to work, it would be cool to post your solution for others to see.

Comment: Absolutely will. Thanks a million Greg.